# My ASP.NET Core (.NET 7) web application deployed on my company's intranet asks for my domain credentials when i launch it. I need to suppress it

Tags: c#, windows, asp.net-core, web-config, windows-authentication

I have deployed a ASP.NET core (.NET 7) web application (uses windows authentication) on my company's local intranet (IIS Server).

When i launch the application using chrome browser, I get a pop that asks for my domain credentials. If i enter my correct credentials, then the application works without any issues.

But if i clear my browser cache and launch my web application again, the credentials popup again.

I need to know how to get rid of the credentials popup.

My application's url is in the following format
**http://myWebApp.mydomain.com**

The following work around works for me.

1. Go to 'Inernet Options'
2. Click on the 'Security' tab
3. Select 'Local Intranet'
4. Click on the 'Sites' button.
5. Click on 'Automatically detect intranet network' checkbox.
6. Click on 'Advanced' button
7. Add my web application's url (http://myWebApp.mydomain.com) in the 'Add this website to the zone:' text box and click on the 'Add' button
8. Click 'Close'
9. Click 'Ok'
10. Click 'Ok'

Could you please help me solve the issue i am facing without having to add my site using 'Internet Options' to the Local Intranet?

Thanks,
Kyle

my **web.config** in the box where i deployed the app looks like the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <authentication>
          <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
          <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
        </authentication>
      </security>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\AuthTest.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

My applications **Program.cs** is as follows :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: Check your config  <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />

Comment: To apply it to your company's domain, have a domain administrator do what you did on your workstation to the company's domain using a Group Policy.

Comment: Did you had a change to check if that's works as expected outside of your intranet boundary?